# Выбрать родителей по условию для дочерних списков

Tags: c#, запрос, linq, .net-core

Имеется такая структура: `город -> List<дом> -> List<квартира>`. Необходимо выбрать  все города и все дома, но выбирать только те квартиры, которые принадлежат запрашиваему человеку.

Пока только так, но он выбирает только там где есть, что неудивительно для Any:

```
cities.Where(x => x.Houses.Any(y => y.Apartments.Any(z => z.MemberId == "4"))).ToList();
```

Код для мокапа, консольное приложение:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cities = new List<City>
            {
                new City
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Houses = new List<House>
                    {
                        new House
                        {
                            Id = 1,
                            CityId = 1,
                            Apartments = new List<Apartment>
                            {
                                new Apartment {Id = 1, MemberId = "1", HouseId = 1},
                                new Apartment {Id = 2, MemberId = "1", HouseId = 1},
                                new Apartment {Id = 3, MemberId = "2", HouseId = 1},
                                new Apartment {Id = 4, MemberId = "3", HouseId = 1}
                            }
                        },
                        new House
                        {
                            Id = 2,
                            CityId = 1,
                            Apartments = new List<Apartment>
                            {
                                new Apartment {Id = 5, MemberId = "3", HouseId = 2},
                                new Apartment {Id = 6, MemberId = "4", HouseId = 2}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                new City
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Houses = new List<House>
                    {
                        new House
                        {
                            Id = 3,
                            CityId = 2,
                            Apartments = new List<Apartment>
                            {
                                new Apartment {Id = 1, MemberId = "5", HouseId = 3},
                                new Apartment {Id = 4, MemberId = "6", HouseId = 3}
                            }
                        },
                        new House
                        {
                            Id = 4,
                            CityId = 2,
                            Apartments = new List<Apartment>
                            {
                                new Apartment {Id = 5, MemberId = "6", HouseId = 4}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var a = cities.Where(x => x.Houses.Any(y => y.Apartments.Any(z => z.MemberId == "4"))).ToList();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class City
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public List<House> Houses { get; set; }
    }

    public class House
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public List<Apartment> Apartments { get; set; }

        public long? CityId { get; set; }
        public City City { get; set; }
    }

    public class Apartment
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string MemberId { get; set; }

        public long HouseId { get; set; }
        public House House { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не трогать исходную коллекцию, то

```
var b = cities
    .Select(city => new City { Id = c.Id, 
        Houses = city.Houses.Select(h => new House { Id = h.Id, 
            Apartments = h.Apartments.Where(apt => apt.MemberId == "4").ToList() }).ToList() })
    .Where(city=>city.Houses.Any(h=>h.Apartments.Any())).ToList()
```

Если трогать, то

```
cities.ForEach(city=>city.Houses
      .ForEach(h=>h.Apartments = h.Apartments.Where(apt=>apt.MemberId == "4").ToList()))
var c = cities.Where(city=>city.Houses.Any(h=>h.Apartments.Any())).ToList();
```

Comment: В первом варианте надо заменить `Id = c.Id` на `Id = city.Id`. Но оба запроса выбирают только то, где есть нужные квартиры, а надо чтобы были все города и все дома, а вот квартиры могут быть null если не подходят под условие. Как вариант можно через foreach просто удалить ненужные квартиры, но хотелось бы через linq

Comment: @Jagailo ну, уберите финальную фмльтрацию `.Where(city=>city.Houses.Any(h=>h.Apartments.Any())).ToList()` из запросов, получите дома без квартир

Comment: Да, действительно работает, спасибо за помощь.